# Using Base64 encoded characters as filename in Android app

Tags: android, base64, filenames

I'm trying to generate filenames in my Android app from a 4 byte byte array. I'm Base64 encoding the byte array with the URL_SAFE option. However, the generated string seems to end with a newline character, which makes it unusable as a filename. Is there anyway to remove the newline?

My code is as follows:

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[4];
myByteArray = generateBytes(myByteArray); // fills the byte array with some data
final String byteString = Base64.encodeToString(myByteArray, Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

After some googling, I found out that in Android, Base64 encoding automatically inserts a newline after the string, and that using the NO_WRAP flag would solve this. However, is the NO_WRAP flag generated output filename safe?

Thanks.

Comment: Just did a quick reading on [Base64 API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html), it seems that both flags cover your requirement. You may consider to use `Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP` (bit-wise OR) to use both flags, then test it! :)

Comment: Yup, I figured that out soon after. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, turns out I can use (Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP) to apply both flags.